# How to display a title over the multiselect attribute value?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, magento-community

I created a multiselect attribute and displayed an image at frontend for that attribute value.I want to display a title for each value when the customer hovers over the feature image.

How can this be done?

Below is the sample like which I wish to keep:

[image]

Comment: provide url of what you have done, if possible

Comment: Sorry @AnilSuthar am doin it in my local machine. Please check my updated question.